# Optimize and vectorize random function in c

Tags: c, optimization, random, vectorization

I programed a function to generate pseudo-random numbers, but my compiler doesn't vectorize this `not vectorized: complicated access pattern`.
How can I achive that the compiler vectorize this?
I use the comand `gcc -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-all-loops -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed -lm -g $1 -o ${2}.O3`

```
    unsigned int seed;
    unsigned int temp;
    #define val13 13
    unsigned int var1 = 214013;
    unsigned int var2 = 2531011;
    inline int myRandom() {
      seed = (var1*seed + var2);
      return (seed>>val13);
    }
```

If I change the code to this I manage to vectorize but I do not get the expected result.

```
inline int myRandom() {
          return ((var1*seed + var2)>>val13);
        }
```

How can I achive the compiler to vectorize this function and get the expected result?

Comment: What about that do you think can be vectorized? Maybe to a FMA instruction?

Comment: Are `var1` and `var2` really variables? They look like constants to me. Maybe you should clarify that fir the compiler (and the rest of us). Constants are usually easier to optimise.

Comment: @rici: Changing them to constants yields the same compiler messages.

Comment: An alternative could be to run the generator separately in each lane: For n-way vectorization, set n seeds, then run a different generator (same function, different seed) in each lane. That will yield different results from an unvectorized version, so whether it is suitable will depend on your needs.

Comment: @eric: yeah, i didn't think it would vectorise. But it's possible that it produces *other* optimisations, and anyway it's a good habit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the given code the shift has no influence on the seed, so that should not cause a problem, i.e., applying `f^4` on each seed-element should be possible (though probably very hard for a compiler to see). However, I think there are PRNGs better suited for vectorization, like SIMDxorshift or SFMT (SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister).

Comment: @chtz: Ah, I missed that; I was thinking `>>13` was before updating the seed. Sure, that makes f^4 easy to compute, so vectorization becomes fairly easy.

Comment: @Desiree You should provide more context (i.e., a [mre]). That function in itself obviously can't be vectorized.

Comment: the variable `seed` is being used before it has been initialized.  The result is undefined behavior.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator function *f* on the seed is a linear congruential generator that is easily composed with itself to implement *f*<sup>2</sup>, *f*<sup>3</sup>, *f*<sup>4</sup>, and so on. Then a vectorized generator can be implemented that prepares an initial vector block from one seed and then uses *f*<sup>*B*</sup> to calculate results in *B* lanes each independent of each other. Here is a proof of concept. Various embellishments are possible, such as keeping a vector of seeds instead of a single seed and modifying `FillRandomVector` to handle arbitrary `N`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define Block   4   //  Number of lanes (elements) in a vector block.


static const unsigned int var1 = 214013;
static const unsigned int var2 = 2531011;


//  Original generator function, modified to take a pointer to the seed.
static inline int MyRandom(unsigned int *seed)
{
    *seed = var1 * *seed + var2;
    return *seed >> 13;
}


//  New parameters for a vectorized generator.
static unsigned int var1Vector;
static unsigned int var2Vector;


/*  Initialize parameters for vectorized generator by computing them from the
    scalar parameters.
*/
static void Initialize(void)
{
    var1Vector = 1;
    var2Vector = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Block; ++i)
    {
        var1Vector *= var1;
        var2Vector = var2Vector * var1 + var2;
    }
}


//  Fill array with generated numbers using scalar method.
static void FillRandomScalar(unsigned int *seed, size_t N, int *Destination)
{
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        Destination[n] = MyRandom(seed);
}


/*  Fill array with generated numbers using vectorizable method.

    For proof of concept only, so handles only certain N:

        N must be a positive multiple of Block.
*/
static void FillRandomVector(unsigned int *seed, size_t N, int *Destination)
{
    //  Prepare a vector of seeds and generate the first block of results.
    unsigned seedVector[Block];
    unsigned int S = *seed;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < Block; ++n)
    {
        S = S * var1 + var2;
        seedVector[n] = S;
        Destination[n] = S >> 13;
    }

    //  Generate the remaining results using independent lanes.
    for (size_t n = Block; n < N; n += Block)
        for (size_t lane = 0; lane < Block; ++lane)
        {
            seedVector[lane] = seedVector[lane] * var1Vector + var2Vector;
            Destination[n + lane] = seedVector[lane] >> 13;
        }

    *seed = seedVector[Block-1];
}


#define N   100


int main(void)
{
    Initialize();

    int expected0[N], observed0[N];
    int expected1[N], observed1[N];

    unsigned int seed;

    seed = 17;
    FillRandomScalar(&seed, N, expected0);
    FillRandomScalar(&seed, N, expected1);

    seed = 17;
    FillRandomVector(&seed, N, observed0);
    FillRandomVector(&seed, N, observed1);

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        if (observed0[n] != expected0[n])
        {
            printf("observed0[%zu] = %d, but expected0 %d.\n",
                n, observed0[n], expected0[n]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        if (observed1[n] != expected1[n])
        {
            printf("observed1[%zu] = %d, but expected1 %d.\n",
                n, observed1[n], expected1[n]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```